# Connect to AWS RDS MySql database with Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-rds, pymysql

I am currently trying to connect to my MySql database created on AWS with a python program using the library PyMySQL.

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='.blablablablabla.us-east.rds.amazonaws.com',
                             user='Username',
                             password='Password',
                             db='nameofmydb',
                             )
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'nameofmydb'")
```

What am I doing wrong? The arguments I gave to the function are correct. Could it be a problem with the MySql driver?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The message is the standard one, returned by mysql server. It means what it says, it can not find the database. Doesn't look like a connectivity problem or a driver issue: it reaches the server and the server returns a message.

Just make sure you have created the database using the CREATE DATABASE command. Use the mysql CLI client to connect to the database and type SHOW DATABASES to see all the available databases.